# mIn java, how would one go about loading a web page into a BufferedReader, as mine will not print?

Tags: java, html, reader, buffered

Hey I a having a little trouble here. I am doing File Writing at school and we got the challenge of reading a webpage. How is it possible to do it? I had a go with a JSoup and an Apache plugin, but neither worked, but I have to use the net import

I am a bit of a noob at coding, so there will probably be  a couple of errors!
Here is my code:

```
    URL oracle = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null){
         System.out.println(inputLine);
    }
    br.close();
```

There is no output from the program, and earlier I managed output but it was in the form of HTML, however I deleted that code, ironically looking for a fix for that issue.

Any help or solutions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you all very much!

Comment: What do you mean _mine will not print_?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I am very tired, well spotted. I meant my code / solution

Comment: Your code doesn't follow the redirect. Try `https://www.oracle.com/index.html`.

Comment: you're not reading the actual file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code example is from [Reading Directly from a URL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html), but the tutorial is old. The url `http://www.oracle.com` now redirects to `https://www.oracle.com/` but you don't follow the redirect.

If you use a URL that does not redirect, like `http://www.google.com` you will see that the code works.

If you want a more robust program that handles redirects, you'll probably want to use a [HttpURLConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) instead of the basic [URL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html), as it has more features for you to use.

Comment: Caveat, the url for google (`http://www.google.com`) might redirect to the localized version/site if it's accessed outside the US. (i.e. from England, it may redirect you to `https://www.google.co.uk`)

Comment: Good point. There's a fair chance that a lot of modern websites will use redirects in one way or another. Your best bet is to use a URL for which you know the HTTP response.

Comment: It works! But now I can't seem to print it - it all is formatted as HTML when printed as a stringbuilder and string. I tried the stringbuilder with and without the html tags, but no avail.

Comment: When you download a web page, you will receive the raw HTML. Are you trying to print it to paper? That won't work. You need a program that will render the HTML (like a web browser) to print it as it looks on the web.